# Dart Angular - get swipe event on mobile

Tags: dart, angular-components

I note that buried down in the Angular_Components library is the HammerJS library, but swipe does not seem to be exposed (only 'touch')

Is there a way to detect and respond to swipe events in Dart?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - Gunter, care to weigh in on this?

Answer (score 0):

We don't support HammerJS today, but you can listen to any native event:

```
<div (touch)="onTouch($event)"></div>
```

Feel free to file an issue on our tracker for better mobile/touch support, this is something we are going to start focusing on soon. Cheers!

Comment: This API does not work anymore, has it been replaced ? @matanlurey